# Connectivity with minimal width

Tags: geometry, terminology

Suppose you have a land-estate $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. You want to be able to drive in your car from each point in $L$ to each other point in $L$. The width of the car is $w$. So, it is not sufficient that $L$ be [path-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_connected) - it should also have a width of at least $w$ in each point in the path.

What term describes this property of being "connected with width at least $w$"?

What are references studying this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid complications from describing how the car should behave in curves, let us suppose it to have the shape of an open disk of diameter $w.$ Then your condition (in addition to pathwise connectedness itself) is equivalent to the set $L_{w/2}$ being pathwise connected, with $L_\epsilon$ defined as the set of points being at least $\epsilon$ removed from the complement of $L.$ Taking complements, this is related to a notion in elementary probabilistic geometry defined as the points that are at most $\epsilon$ *removed* from a given set. I think it is described in Luis Santalo's book "Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability".